# reload directives on change page angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, reload, angular2-directives

I write some code in angular but I have a problem with the reload of my directives when I change the page. So, the files that are included on all my pages not reload when I go in a page from menu.
This is some code in a app.js file:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('dashboard', {
    url:'/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/main.html',
    resolve: {
        loadMyDirectives:function($ocLazyLoad){
            return $ocLazyLoad.load(
            {
                name:'sbAdminApp',
                files:[
                'scripts/directives/header/header.js',
                'scripts/directives/header/header-notification/header-notification.js',
                'scripts/directives/sidebar/sidebar.js',
                'scripts/directives/sidebar/sidebar-search/sidebar-search.js'
                ]
            })
```

And some code from a controller of a page:

```
"use strict";
  angular
    .module("sbAdminApp",['ngRoute'])
     .controller("ServicesCtrl",function($scope,getasap,NgTableParams,ngDialog){

    })
```

Comment: Are you going to tell us what the problem is...?

Comment: the problem is that the code inside the files included in app.js ('scripts/directives/header/header.js',              'scripts/directives/header/header-notification/header-notification.js',) not ar refreshed when I load another page

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a header across all your views, you shouldn't put it in your lazy load. Your index.html should look like this:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as appCtrl">

<!-- Navigation -->
<div header></div>
<!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-wrapper" ui-view></div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->


</body>
```